# Installing newest version of NodeJS on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, apt, nodejs

I've been trying to install NodeJS version 12, but I've been running into some issues where using

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

is installing version 4.2.6 and nothing I've done seems to change this.
I have tried using

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
```

and then running

```
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

which installs 4.2.6 again.
I have checked the nodesource_setup.sh which contains the following lines

```
SCRSUFFIX="_12.x"
NODENAME="Node.js 12.x"
NODEREPO="node_12.x"
NODEPKG="nodejs"
```

I am not sure how to proceed to correctly install the newest version of NodeJs and NPM on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

Comment: How are you checking what verion of NodeJS you are running?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using "Linux Brew" for installing NodeJS. At least that's what I do to have the latest version of node.

Follow the instructions of installing the brew from [here](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux). then run:

```
$ brew install node
```

Now you have the last version:

```
$ node --version
v13.11.0
```

Which lives here:

```
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node
```

No messing with sources.list and dependencies.